# JsonConvert.SerializeObject Splitting String into Array of Letters

Tags: c#, json

I have a controller which is supposed to return some location information by locationid. I return a Location object, then use JsonConvert.SerializeObject to turn it into a string, which I pass back to the web page. JsonConvert.SerializeObject is turning any strings into an array of letters. That is, if I had an object:

```
public class Location
{
    public string Address { get; set; }
}

Location l = new Location();
l.Address = "123 Main St";
var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(l);
```

then the I get the following result in my json variable:

```
{ "Address": ["1", "2", "3", "", "M", "a", "i", "n", "", "S", "t" ]}
```

Has anyone ever seen this before? I haven't tried anything because I'm not really sure what to even try. The Location object coming back is valid. I'm using MVC 5 in C#. Is there something in my Location object I should check for that might be causing this? It's built into a set of proprietary dll's we use across a variety of projects, but as far as I know no one else needs to convert to json (I'm the only web developer).

Comment: I'm not getting that: https://dotnetfiddle.net/RKsE6r

Comment: perhaps you need to decorate your class with the [Serializable] attribute?

Comment: Is that definitely the code for `Location`? I'm guessing that it might not be. Can you view the source code?

Comment: @Scott yes, I have to look through the repo. I'll edit the question when I find it.

Comment: Ok. So it's not a string, it's an NString. I casted to string and all was fixed.